# Keyword Google Rankings GA / Datastudio

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-data-studio

I have a question about to Google Data Studio/Google Analytics/Search Console.

I am wondering how to report on keyword top movers as per the attached screenshot?
I have been trying to find the metrics/dimensions through GA and datastudio but cannot seem to find. Anyone shed some light how to achieve this?

Thank you

[image: description]

Comment: You would do best to connect Data Studio (DS) to Google Search Console (GSC). GA doesnt track GSC data, it gets tracked by GSC and then a portion of available data is imported from GSC into GA if the two are linked.
The following is a good template to start with:
https://www.aleydasolis.com/en/search-engine-optimization/using-google-data-studio-actionable-search-console-performance-report/

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to compare two date periods and display a column of the numerical difference of a certain metric from the first period to the second. It is possible to do this in Data Studio with the steps below.

- In the Data tab, set the comparison date range.
- Go to the Style tab. In the Metrics section, you now have sub-sections for each metric you selected, each titled 'Column #1', 'Column #2', etc.
- Use the checkboxes in each sub-section to toggle 'Show Compare' and 'Show Absolute Change'.

The caveat to this is you cannot sort the comparison column. To get around it you can export the table as a spreadsheet and sort/manipulate it from there.

Another work around is [to blend the data](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/3750123?hl=en&msgid=21266808), as suggested by a user in Google's support forums. Having tried this myself however, it's not ideal if you want to dynamically update the date range since you'd have to create a new blended data source each time. The benefit of this method is that you can work with the table data in Data Studio instead of exporting to Excel.

As a side-note, sorting by compare in Data Studio is one of the top requested features. If you think it would be useful, give it an upvote by starring the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64262260.

If you want to see top growing keywords, use Google Search Console as the data source and use Clicks as the metric. There will be two available data source types - use Site Impressions if you don't need the landing page data or do need the average position, and use URL Impressions if you want the landing page. The difference is that Site Impressions aggregates the metrics for all landing pages that appear for the query within a date range, whereas URL Impressions separates each landing page-and-query combo into its own row.

Edit: I forgot to mention another method that's right in Search Console. If you compare two periods in the Performance report, and then select only one metric, now you have an additional column titled "Difference", which you can sort by:

[image]